# grails url mappings controller

Tags: url, grails, controller, mapping

In my app - grails 3.0 I'm trying to return custom URL: /book/showbook/2
The controller has two actions:

action1 - collecting user form and create object book

action2 - showing the information of the created book.

Spring security plugin is installed.

**Problem**: instead of displaying: **/book/showbook/2** the result of the submit button is: 
**/book/showbook**.

URL mappings code:

```
  static mappings = {
            "/book/showbook/$id?(.$format)?"(controller: 'game', action: 'showbook')

            "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
                constraints {
                }
            }
```

View action 1 code:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" params:[id: ${bookID}]>Submit data</button>
```

Action2 code:

```
def showbook(Book book) {
        respond book
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are creating the form as it should be. 
You can read the Grails official form tag. 
http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/form.html

Please try this

```
<g:form name="book" action="showbook" id="${bookID}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Submit data</button>
</g:form>
```

Please make sure that ${bookID} is defined somewhere in your gsp or passed from your modal to the appropriate view otherwise, it will not work.

Comment: I'm using a form but I didn't paste it just for the sake of readability. I'll check my form declaration if I'm missing something. Thanx

Comment: Yeah you are right my mistake was in the form: <g:form name="create-new-form" url="[action:'showbook',controller:'book']">. It was hardcoded which causes the strange behavior. Thanx